# 'label1' is not declared | it's defined in an include file

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I get the following error when I try to build in VS but it **works** at runtime w/o issue.

> Error  BC30451 'label1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

How do I tell Visual Studio that the asp control, `label1` is defined?

*Home.aspx*

```
<!--#include virtual="header.inc"-->
<!--#include virtual="shared.aspx"-->
```

*Shared.aspx*

```
<!--#include virtual="header.inc"-->

<script runat="server">
    label1.text = "Some value"
</script>
```

*Header.inc*

```
<asp:label id="label1" runat="server" />
```

This prevents me from being able to use the debugger on files like *Shared.aspx*.

Note: I've inherited a fairly large code base that does this everywhere so changing the pattern is not a very feasible answer for me, unfortunately.

Comment: But it's not defined.  Not at compile time anyway, which is all Visual Studio has until the code is executed.  As with far too many legacy codebases, it sounds like the choice is between fixing the code or learning to ignore the "error".  I recommend the former, but budgets and schedules often get in the way of that.

Comment: I see, thanks .  What's is the correct fix in webforms?  [User controls](https://www.guru99.com/asp-net-controls-webforms.html)? @David

Comment: A combination of Master Pages and User Controls.